# What do the "flatten" and "expand" options of grunt-replace do?

Tags: node.js, gruntjs

What do the "flatten" and "expand" options of grunt-replace do?

[They are not really documented!](https://www.npmjs.org/package/grunt-replace)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out grunt documentation about [Building the files object automatically](http://gruntjs.com/configuring-tasks#building-the-files-object-dynamically).

- `expand`: Enable file options
- `flatten`: Remove all path parts from generated `dest` paths